# DRF - django_filters -Using custom methods

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework, django-filters

I have a model like this:

```
class Agreement(models.Model):
    file_no = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    contract_date = models.DateField()
    contract_time = models.IntegerField()

    @property
    def calculate_expiry_date(self):
        return self.contract_date + relativedelta(years=self.contract_time)

    @property
    def is_expired(self):
        return (self.contract_date + relativedelta(years=self.contract_time)) < timezone.now().date()
```

`is_expired`  function returns true or false for each agreement

and I have a simple filter like this:

```
class AgreementFilter(filters.FilterSet):
    file_no = filters.NumberFilter(lookup_expr='icontains')

    class Meta:
        model = Agreement
        fields = ['file_no',]
```

I  think that I cannot filter on the property field because Django filters operate at the database level. So how can I make it work to filter agreement model objects if it is valid or invalid or either true or false

Comment: What do you mean by 'make it work to filter agreement' ?

Comment: I wanna filter the Agreement model objects if it is valid or invalid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to write a custom filter for filtering the expired and valid agreements by using the 'method' parameter to specify a custom method - [see django-filter docs](https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ref/filters.html#method)

```
from datetime import timedelta
from django.db.models import F, Case, When, BooleanField
from django_filters import rest_framework as filters

class AgreementFilter(filters.FilterSet):

    file_no = filters.NumberFilter(lookup_expr='icontains')
    is_expired = filters.BooleanFilter(method='filter_is_expired')

    class Meta:
        model = Agreement
        fields = ['file_no',] 

      def filter_is_expired(self, queryset, name, value):
        if value is not None:
            queryset = queryset.annotate(

                expired=Case(When(contract_date__lt=timezone.now().date() - (timedelta(days=365) * F('contract_time')),
                             then=True), default=False, output_field=BooleanField())).filter(expired=value)
        return queryset
```

Queryset will return if the object of the agreement is either true or false by calculation:

**For expired agreements**

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/agreement/?is_expired=True
```

and 
**For valid agreements**

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/agreement/?is_expired=False
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add new field to `Agreement` model which keeps the expiry date of the agreement:

```
expiry_date = models.DateField()
```

If `contract_time` field is for the number of years the contract remains valid and you know it at the time of adding a new contract, then you can calculate the expiry date just as you are doing now and add it to `expiry_date` field without needing the property decorator.

Now you want it to be done automatically when new records are added, for this you can use pre_save [signals](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/signals/).

```
from django.dispatch import receiver
from django.db.models import signals

@receiver(signals.pre_save, sender=WorkDone)
def calculate_expiry_date(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    instance.expiry_date = instances.contract_date + \
       relativedelta(years=instance.contract_time)
```

For the filtering part you can use current date to filter records. Since you are using DRF this will be quite easy, in frontend just use current date and pass it as filter argument to show show only agreements which has date greater than current date.

Comment: Thanks for the solution..  but I have done it by writing a custom filter which is an easier method for me.